# Golang clean items out of channel that will not be read

Tags: http, asynchronous, go

I am working on an http endpoint that will receive a request from a client and block until it receives an "ack" for that request from another server or until it passes a timeout. The communication between my code and the server is not included in this sample, but you can assume that for each request, an ack may be received eventually.

Since many requests will pass through my module in short periods of time, I cannot assume that a given ack is related the the request I am blocking on. **EDIT:** Clarification here since it has caused some confusion. Both requests and acks are received by the controller from external sources. This is why I am handling them asychronously. **/EDIT** For this reason, my code places acks back on the channel if they are not relevant. It is also important to note that http.ListenAndServe calls my functions asynchronously.

If the request is acked within the timeout, there are no problems. However, it the ack comes after the timeout has passed, it will be added to a channel and never removed. This will cause the channel to fill up. I am afraid to use a "cancel" channel because it is also possible that no ack will be received for a given request, causing the cancel channel to fill as well.

**The Question**: How can I keep late acks from filling my channel?/How can I identify and remove late acks?

Code below. No play.golang.org link because http.ListenAndServe :/

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const timeout = 10

func startEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var ack string
    timer := time.NewTimer(time.Second * timeout)
    defer timer.Stop()

    m := r.RequestURI[len("/start/"):]
    fmt.Print(m)
AckRecycle:
    for {
        select {
        case ack = <-acks:
            if ack == m {
                //What we found was our own ack
                fmt.Print("+")
                w.Write([]byte("Ack received for " + ack))
                break AckRecycle
            } else {
                //What we found on the channel wasn't for us
                fmt.Print(".")
                time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
                acks <- ack
            }
        case <-timer.C:
            //We ran out of time waiting for our ack
            w.Write([]byte("Timeout waiting for " + m))
            break AckRecycle
        default:
            //Channel was empty
            fmt.Print("-")
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
        }
    }
    return
}

func ackEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ack := r.RequestURI[len("/ack/"):]
    acks <- ack
    fmt.Print("Ack for " + ack)
    w.Write([]byte("Thanks!"))
    return
}

var acks = make(chan string, 10)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ack/", ackEndpoint)
    http.HandleFunc("/start/", startEndpoint)

    http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8888", nil)
}
```

**NOTE**: To test this, run it on your local machine. Curl/Wget `127.0.0.1:8888/start/bob` and then Curl/Wget `127.0.0.1:8888/ack/bob`. You can replace bob with any string to see the behavior.

I'm new to Go. Feel free to provide other feedback in the comments.

Comment: if you can't related the ack to your request, then the acks are completely useless. no ? Handle the ack on the same channel of the request. Use a token to identify the request (generate a uuid and pass that along).

Comment: The ack will have a uuid that matches up with a request (or in this example, a name string). In the "Note" I have used "bob" as the name string that matches a request with an ack. The problem is that the ack may come after the request times out, or never at all. The question is how do I handle late/absent acks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a `map` of "uuids in process"; when you receive a `/start/` add it to the map, and when you receive an `ack` (or when the request times out) remove it. If you receive an ack that isn't in the map, discard it immediately.

Be careful, as maps are not thread-safe by default.

Comment: This answer addresses the underlying problem in my thinking: I was looking for a way to keep track of which acks are valid and invalid. The more effective way is to keep track of which requests are valid and invalidate all unrelated acks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be trying to write Go in the asynchronous style of Akka. This is a hard choice; idiomatic Go should be easier. The flaw is here: "*I cannot assume that a given ack is related the the request I am blocking on*".

Instead, you need to handle each request with simple sequential steps and send the ack directly back to its client. For this, each request would need its own service goroutine.

Comment: I appreciate this response. It would appear that the wording of my question was poor. There are three interacting services in this scenario: the client who sends requests, the controller for which the code is given, and an external set of servers that send acks to the controller when work is finished. From the perspective of the controller, random requests and acks are arriving all the time, and these are not necessarily in a particular order. Because of this, there isn't a "sequential" way to handle the requests and acks. I hope that clarifies the situation.